# Dataclass in python when the attribute doesn't respect naming rules

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

If you have data like this (from a yaml file):

```
items:
  C>A/G>T: "#string"
  C>G/G>C: "#string"
  ...
```

How would load that in a dataclass that is explicit about the keys and type it has?
Ideally I would have:

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class X:
    C>A/G>T: str
    C>G/G>C: str
...
```

Update:

```
SBS_Mutations = TypedDict(
    "SBS_Mutations",
    {
        "C>A/G>T": str,
        "C>G/G>C": str,
        "C>T/G>A": str,
        "T>A/A>T": str,
        "T>C/A>G": str,
        "T>G/A>C": str,
    },
)

my_data = {....}

SBS_Mutations(my_data) # not sure how to use it here
```

Comment: The attrs of the dataclass have to be valid Python identifiers. You can do something like you need with Pydantic library, which is like extended deluxe dataclasses, see https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#reserved-names

Comment: @blunova what do you mean? the attributes of a dataclass have to be proper names..

Comment: you need something like what Pydantic offers - a translation layer between the keys of the input data (from your yaml) into valid python identifiers that can be used as attributes of the class instance. https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#alias-generator e.g. string substitutions to translate `C>A/G>T` into `c_a_g_t`

Comment: alternatively... using dictionaries in your code instead of dataclass, since dict can have string keys.  You might check out https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict

Comment: @Anentropic hmm, this is not valid `class A(TypedDict):
    "C>A/G>T": str ` , where you revering to something else?

Comment: ah yes, you'd have to use the "functional syntax" rather than the class def style, so: `X = TypedDict('X', {'C>A/G>T': str, 'C>G/G>C': str})`

Comment: @Anentropic thanks, looks like what I want but not sure how to use it, I updated the question

Comment: Yep you can do literally what you showed (assuming `my_data` is a dict you have loaded from yaml). Otherwise they behave exactly as a dictionary

Answer (score 2):

if you want symbols like that, they obviously can't be Python identifiers, and then, it is meaningless to want to use the facilities that a dataclass, with attribute access, gives you.

Just keep your data in dictionaries, or in Pandas dataframes, where such names can be column titles.

Otherwise, post a proper code snippet with a minimum example of *where* you are getting the data from, and then, one can add in an answer, a proper place to translate your orignal name into a valid Python attribute name, and help building a dynamic data class with it.

Comment: the data is given by clients and they symbolise genetic mutations... but it feels like if I have to go and translate keys and do all that dancing around to get a value, it's more confusing then using a plain dict

Comment: you can do a _lot_ with Python, like having classes thaat stores the mutations in "smart ways" so they know how to combien withi each other, and so on. otherwise, just translate these expressiosn to strigns like 'C_replaces_A_and_G_replaces_T for exactly waht you asked.

Comment: You could have a mapping dict between yaml and class `C>A…`  to `c_gt_a…` (which pydantic aliasing might do).  Then reverse that to get the originals as  *labels* back for reports.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a good use case for my [`dotwiz`](https://dotwiz.readthedocs.io/) library, which I have recently published. This provides a `dict` subclass which enables attribute-style dot access for nested keys.

As of the recent release, it offers a `DotWizPlus` implementation (a wrapper around a `dict` object) that also case transforms keys so that they are valid lower-cased, python identifier names, as shown below.

```py
# requires the following dependencies:
#   pip install PyYAML dotwiz
import yaml
from dotwiz import DotWizPlus

yaml_str = """
items:
  C>A/G>T: "#string"
  C>G/G>C: "#string"
"""

yaml_dict = yaml.safe_load(yaml_str)
print(yaml_dict)

dw = DotWizPlus(yaml_dict)
print(dw)

assert dw.items.c_a_g_t == '#string'  # True

print(dw.to_attr_dict())
```

Output:

```
{'items': {'C>A/G>T': '#string', 'C>G/G>C': '#string'}}
✪(items=✪(c_a_g_t='#string', c_g_g_c='#string'))
{'items': {'c_a_g_t': '#string', 'c_g_g_c': '#string'}}
```

*NB*: This currently fails when accessing the key `items` from just a `DotWiz` instance, as the key name conflicts with the builtin attribute `dict.items()`. I've currently submitted a [bug request](https://github.com/rnag/dotwiz/issues/4) and hopefully work through this one edge case in particular.

#### Type Hinting

If you want type-hinting or auto-suggestions for field names, you can try something like this where you subclass from `DotWizPlus`:

```py
import yaml
from dotwiz import DotWizPlus


class Item(DotWizPlus):
    c_a_g_t: str
    c_g_g_c: str

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, yaml_string: str, loader=yaml.safe_load):
        yaml_dict = loader(yaml_str)
        return cls(yaml_dict['items'])


yaml_str = """
items:
  C>A/G>T: "#string1"
  C>G/G>C: "#string2"
"""

dw = Item.from_yaml(yaml_str)
print(dw)
# ✪(c_a_g_t='#string1', c_g_g_c='#string2')

assert dw.c_a_g_t == '#string1'  # True

# auto-completion will work, as IDE knows the type is a `str`
# dw.c_a_g_t.
```

##### Dataclasses

If you would still prefer dataclasses for type-hinting purposes, there is another library you can also check out called [dataclass-wizard](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/), which can help to simplify this task as well.

More specifically, `YAMLWizard` makes it easier to load/dump a class object with YAML. Note that this uses the `PyYAML` library behind the scenes by default.

Note that I couldn't get the case-transform to work in this case, since I guess it's a bug in the underlying `to_snake_case()` implementation. I'm also going to submit a bug request to look into this edge case. However, for now it should work if the key name in YAML is specified a bit more explicitly:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from dataclass_wizard import YAMLWizard, json_field

yaml_str = """
items:
  C>A/G>T: "#string"
  C>G/G>C: "#string"
"""


@dataclass
class Container(YAMLWizard):
    items: 'Item'


@dataclass
class Item:
    c_a_g_t: str = json_field('C>A/G>T')
    c_g_g_c: str = json_field('C>G/G>C')


c = Container.from_yaml(yaml_str)
print(c)

# True
assert c.items.c_g_g_c == c.items.c_a_g_t == '#string'
```

Output:

```
Container(items=Item(c_a_g_t='#string', c_g_g_c='#string'))
```